# Native Android CSS settings

Tags: android, css

I have to make a mobile-friendly website (has a couple of articles and a form element inside) and the UI has to be as close to native Android UI as possible. Are there any stylesheets or gists available of a typical Samsung Android device UI?

Comment: search for material designs guidelines

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

If you have an android device you could get an HTML writer and test and edit from that app.

If you don't have android you ca get them on IOS as well.

Otherwise you could find the pixel dimensions of an S10 and set your HTML output size to those same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Onsen UI](https://onsen.io/).